# Can someone explain how to implement style encapsulation in a React app?

Tags: css, reactjs

Looking at a webpage created with React, I see class names like `class="pmjY9Fa_`. I know about encapsulation, but am wondering when does the turning of human readable class names into a unique string happen? Looking at my own app (created with the basic create-react-app) the class names are still normal. Do I have to npm install something like css-modules? And if I do, what happens then? Like, I have to eject my CRA to add css-modules to my webpack configuration so when the app builds (either for development or production) the style names are hashed? Also, isn't it a bad development experience if the style names are all hashed?

My question his, how can I set up style encapsulation with hashed classes and still have a decent development experience with human readable class names?

*edit:* Also I'm trying to figure out how this is done without using Styled Components because the project I'm going to work on already uses scss co-located with the JSX files.

Comment: See this : https://medium.com/@hammadtariq65/style-encapsulation-in-reactjs-ba4e3212a9f

Comment: use CSS modules or StyledComponents

Comment: As suggested in the other comments, I'd recommend the Styled Components library. It's pretty great: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Comment: *"project I'm going to work on already uses scss co-located with the JSX files"*: You should use CSS Modules. That is very simple: Just renames the files (e.g. `myButton.module.scss`), import (`import styles from "./myButton.module.scss"`) and use (`<div className={styles.someClass}>...</div>`).

Answer (score 2):

***CSS Modules***

> create-react-app v2+

comes with out-of-box support for **CSS Modules**.

You **DO NOT** need to

- eject,
- Perform any additional webpack configs manually, or
- Perform any npm install

Using CSS Modules with create-react-app (v2+) is very easy

1. Name the css files associated with the component name like [name].module.css
2. Add CSS classes to this file as you normally do, and import this css file into the React component like `import styles from './[Name].module.css'`
3. Use the classes as you normally would like `<header className={styles.header}>…</header>`

When your application runs, the class names in the rendered DOM will be automatically [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to prevent global conflicts. The runtime name will be something like [name]_header__1RvjY instead of just header, for example.

Here is a [link](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/css-modules-react/) explaining this in more detail. Here is the [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) to create-react-app CSS modules docs.

***The second option is styled component***
Here is the [official docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started) to get started. It is equally easy and it is just a matter of preference which one you choose.

So, in summary, whichever option you choose, you do not need to worry about global conflicts and have great developer experience.